# Некорректный предпросмотр таблиц

Tags: дефект, редактор, markdown, таблицы, предварительный-просмотр

Если при оформлении таблицы не сделать пустую строку, то предпросмотрщик таблицу распознает, а в конечном сообщении она схлопнется.

Пример
|C|
|-|
|1|

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Известная история](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359192/339911). Вообще, получается, что итоговый результат кривой, а не предпросмотр.

Comment: Оставлю здесь ссылку на [багрепорт](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support/357596#357596)